# How to cover the line with tests

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have this code:

```
updateAlarmWithTag(alarm: AlarmData) {
this.geometricLayers.markers.forEach((marker) => {
  if (marker.tag === alarm.tagInfo.tag && marker.layer) {
    if (alarm.alarm) {
      const date = new Date(alarm.ts);
      const format = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss';
      const locale = $localize.locale != null ? $localize.locale : 'en-US';

      const content = this.mapDrawService.changePopUpContent(
        parseInt(marker.id),
        'Alarmed - ' + formatDate(date, format, locale) + '<br>' + alarm.alarm.description,
      );
      if (content) {
        marker.layer.getPopup()?.setContent(content);
      }
      marker.layer.getElement()?.classList.add('alarm-blink');
    } else {
      const content = this.mapDrawService.changePopUpContent(parseInt(marker.id), 'Normalized');
      if (content) {
        marker.layer.getPopup()?.setContent(content);
      }
      marker.layer.getElement()?.classList.remove('alarm-blink');
    }
  }
});
```

And i have this tests:

```
describe('updateAlarmWithTag', () => {
it('should call classList.add when alarm is true', () => {
  const tagInfo: TagInfo = {
    device: '1234568',
    tag: '1_AI_0001',
    type: 'testtype',
  };
  const range: Range = {
    max: 10,
    min: 5,
  };
  const alarm: Alarm = {
    description: 'Chuva Forte',
    range: range,
  };
  const alarmData: AlarmData = {
    alarm: alarm,
    tagInfo: tagInfo,
    value: 7.12398343,
    ts: new Date(),
  };
  const marker = {
    tag: '1_AI_0001',
    layer: {
      getElement: () => ({ classList: { add: jasmine.createSpy() } }),
      getPopup: () => ({ getPopup: { setContent: jasmine.createSpy() } }),
    } as unknown as L.Marker,
  } as unknown as MarkerLayerViewInfo;

  component.geometricLayers.markers = [marker];
  component.updateAlarmWithTag(alarmData);
  expect(component.geometricLayers.markers[0].layer?.getElement()?.classList.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith;
  expect(component.geometricLayers.markers[0].layer?.getPopup()?.setContent).toHaveBeenCalled;
});

it('should call classList.remove when alarm is false', () => {
  const tagInfo: TagInfo = {
    device: '1234568',
    tag: '1_AI_0001',
    type: 'testtype',
  };
  const alarmData: AlarmData = {
    tagInfo: tagInfo,
    value: 7.12398343,
    ts: new Date(),
  };
  const marker = {
    tag: '1_AI_0001',
    layer: {
      getElement: () => ({ classList: { remove: jasmine.createSpy() } }),
      getPopup: () => ({ getPopup: () => ({ setContent: jasmine.createSpy() }) }),
    } as unknown as L.Marker,
  } as unknown as MarkerLayerViewInfo;

  component.geometricLayers.markers = [marker];
  component.updateAlarmWithTag(alarmData);
  expect(component.geometricLayers.markers[0].layer?.getElement()?.classList.remove).toHaveBeenCalledWith;
  expect(component.geometricLayers.markers[0].layer?.getPopup()?.setContent).toHaveBeenCalled;
});
it('should not update marker if layer element is null', () => {
  const tagInfo: TagInfo = {
    device: '1234568',
    tag: '1_AI_0001',
    type: 'testtype',
  };
  const alarm: Alarm = {
    description: 'Chuva Forte',
    range: { min: 0, max: 100 },
  };
  const alarmData: AlarmData = {
    alarm: alarm,
    tagInfo: tagInfo,
    value: 50,
    ts: new Date(),
  };
  const marker = {
    tags: { lat: '1_AI_0001', lng: '1_AI_0001' },
    latLng: [{ lat: 19, lng: 44 }],
    layer: {
      getElement: () => null,
      getPopup: () => ({ getPopup: () => ({ setContent: jasmine.createSpy() }) }),
    } as unknown as L.Marker,
  } as unknown as MarkerLayerViewInfo;
  component.geometricLayers.markers = [marker];
  component.updateAlarmWithTag(alarmData);
  expect(component.geometricLayers.markers[0].layer?.getElement()?.classList.add).not.toHaveBeenCalled;
  expect(component.geometricLayers.markers[0].layer?.getElement()?.classList.remove).not.toHaveBeenCalled;
  expect(component.geometricLayers.markers[0].layer?.getPopup()?.setContent).toHaveBeenCalled;
});
```

[image]

How can I achieve test coverage for lines containing marker.layer.getPopup()?.setContent(content) in my updateAlarmWithTag function? My current tests are not covering these lines and I'm looking for ways to address this coverage gap. What is the best approach to solve this issue?

Comment: SO questions need to be written completely in English, and [images of code/logs/errors need to be replaced with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).

Comment: i make changes, its good now ?